# SFDX error on apiVersion

Tags: salesforcedx

Yesterday I started learning Lightning Web Components on Trailhead, installing the new CLI and updating the VS Code extensions as instructed. I got a pre-release Spring 19 dev org and enabled it as a hub, then created a Spring 19 (apiVersion 45) scratch org, etc.

Now, I'm going back to work on my old project, not LWC, using a previously created scratch org (Winter 19, apiVersion 44). When I tried to push my changes, I got this error:

> ERROR:  The configured apiVersion 45.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 44.0.

I don't know how to fix this. Not sure if it's simply a config setting I can change in VS Code, or if I have to revert my CLI to a previous version. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_troubleshoot_api_sync.htm).

```
sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=44.0
```